# FullCalendar event sorting ignores end

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm having an issue sorting my FullCalendar properly and I haven't been able to find a solution for it.

I want the FullCalendar to sort the events based on Start and End and it seems to me as if on certain days the sorting works fine, such as on September 9, but e.g. on September 12 the sorting doesn't work correctly, as it shows 9pm before 6pm and then 8am shows up.

This is my calendar initialization code:

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    events: events,
    eventOrder: ['start', 'end'],
    eventOrderStrict: true,
    timeFormat: 'H:mm',
    height: 'auto',
    displayEventEnd: false,
    eventClick: function (e) {
        console.log(e.event.start)
    }
});
```

I've tried different combinations of eventOrder options, but it doesn't seem to do much for me at all.

9th September, order (which is correct):

- MASIK SIORAQ (12am)
- PAARNAQ / GR-6-162 (12am)
- NUUSSISOQ (4pm)
- NAIN BANKER (9pm)

10th September, order (incorrect):

- MASIK SIORAQ (12 am)
- PAARNAQ / GR-6-162 (12 am)
- NUUSSISOQ (4pm)
- NAIN BANKER (9pm)
- MINIK ARCTICA (6pm)
- BELLE ISLE BANKER (9pm)

On 10th September, why does MINIK ARCTICA show after BELLE ISLE BANKER, when the time of the event is earlier in the day?

[image: Current view of the calendar]

Events JSON

```
[{
    "title": "MASIK SIORAQ",
    "start": "2021-08-31T22:00:01.000Z",
    "end": "2021-09-30T21:59:59.000Z",
    "backgroundColor": "#66DBB8",
    "borderColor": "#66DBB8",
    "display": "block",
    "sortOrder": 0
},
{
    "title": "PAARNAQ / GR-6-162",
    "start": "2021-09-03T22:00:01.000Z",
    "end": "2021-09-30T21:59:59.000Z",
    "backgroundColor": "#1F85DE",
    "borderColor": "#1F85DE",
    "display": "block",
    "sortOrder": 1
},
{
    "title": "NUUSSISOQ",
    "start": "2021-09-09T14:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2021-09-11T16:00:00.000Z",
    "backgroundColor": "#65DE1F",
    "borderColor": "#65DE1F",
    "display": "block",
    "sortOrder": 2
},
{
    "title": "NAIN BANKER",
    "start": "2021-09-09T19:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2021-09-14T16:00:00.000Z",
    "backgroundColor": "#1E26C1",
    "borderColor": "#1E26C1",
    "display": "block",
    "sortOrder": 3
},
{
    "title": "MINIK ARCTICA",
    "start": "2021-09-10T16:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2021-09-13T19:00:00.000Z",
    "backgroundColor": "#1E26C1",
    "borderColor": "#1E26C1",
    "display": "block",
    "sortOrder": 4
},
{
    "title": "BELLE ISLE BANKER",
    "start": "2021-09-10T19:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2021-08-14T16:00:00.000Z",
    "backgroundColor": "#1E26C1",
    "borderColor": "#1E26C1",
    "display": "block",
    "sortOrder": 5
},
{
    "title": "HDMS LAUGE KOCH",
    "start": "2021-09-12T06:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2021-09-15T05:00:00.000Z",
    "backgroundColor": "#9666DB",
    "borderColor": "#9666DB",
    "display": "block",
    "sortOrder": 6
},
{
    "title": "TULU",
    "start": "2021-09-12T16:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2021-09-17T16:00:00.000Z",
    "backgroundColor": "#1E26C1",
    "borderColor": "#1E26C1",
    "display": "block",
    "sortOrder": 7
}]
```

Comment: Since we can't see your event data we can't really help you. Please update your question to provide the relevant events you're having a problem with - in JSON format please - and tell us what result you expected (instead of the one you are getting). Thanks.

Comment: P.S. Also please ensure you have an up-to-date version of fullCalendar. Note that (as per the documentation) the eventOrderStrict option was only introduced in 5.7. Earlier versions of 5.x will not recognise it.

Comment: I've updated my question with the events JSON. I'm using the newest version as per 5 days ago and I can see that EventOrderStrict does have an effect on the calendar view. I'm not sure how to elaborate further on what my problem is and what I'm expecting to happen. The event order is correct in certain cases, but in other cases it's not. I'm expecting it to always order by EventStart and EventEnd.

Comment: `I'm not sure how to elaborate further`... Ok. so, using the data you've provided, just give me a simple list showing what order you expect those events to appear in on the date in question

Comment: Also we don't need _all_ your events. Just the ones which are involved in your problem (it needs to be a [mre], remember), please, then we don't have to wade through mountains of irrelevant info to find what's useful. You mentioned September 9th and 12th in the question, so probably only events which overlap either of those dates are going to be necessary for the question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks - I've shortened the events array and updated my question with more specifics on expected behaviour and actual behaviour.

Comment: Ok. But now you're talking about 12th September in one place and 10th in another place. Which one are you actually having the issue with? Please ensure the question text is consistent. Also, you said `On 10th September, why does MINIK ARCTICA show after BELLE ISLE BANKER, when the time of the event is earlier in the day`...but in your picture, MINIK ARCTICA appears first.

Comment: I'm bringing up different days because this is a general problem. It's not limited to just two specific days. This happens throughout the entire calendar. The issue is very confusing and thus it's very difficult for me to explain it. One specific example: MINIK ARCTICA is BEFORE BELLE ISLE BANKER, while MINIK ARCTICA is earlier in the day and thus MINIK ARCTICA should be displayed first...

Comment: `MINIK ARCTICA is BEFORE BELLE ISLE BANKER`...yes. "BEFORE" means "earlier than". And in your picture, MINIK ARCTICA is shown _before_ BELLE ISLE BANKER on 10th September. That's because MINIK ARCTICA event starts _before_ BELLE ISLE BANKER. This is totally logical. MINIK ARCTICA starts at 16:00:00 UTC. BELLIE ISLE BANKER starts at 19:00:00 UTC. And they both start on the same date. Therefore, MINIK ARCTICA appears first on the calendar. It's all totally normal. I don't understand what you think the problem is, with that example?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to talk about NAIN BANKER instead of BELLE ISLE BANKER? Please double-check what you have written, compared with your data and your picture. (I say this because it would make more sense to ask about NAIN BANKER, as that appears to have a later start time, yet shows up earlier on the 10th. However you have to remember the "start" includes the _date_ as well as the _time_. Therefore the _overall_ start point for NAIN BANKER is earlier than MINIK ARCTICA, which is why it appears first.)

Comment: Ah okay. I see the logic now. My problem is indeed the fact that when an event starts (even from another day), it's on any day still sorted by its start date. I was hoping to have the date always sorted by its hours, but I guess I can do that by adding a parameter to the event with the 24H time and then order by that. I'll give that a shot. Thanks for your patience - feel free to make an answer to my question and I'll mark it.

Comment: `I guess I can do that by adding a parameter to the event with the 24H time and then order by that`...that's definitely worth a try, although I'm not sure what it would do with a multi-day event like that because it will already be aligned further up the list because there's nothing else on its starting day which would cause it to move. And bear in mind that, for example, NAIN BANKER doesn't start at 9pm on the 10th - actually the earliest time on the 10th that it covers is `00:00` (midnight). It spans the entire day. So IMHO it still would be misleading to place it below MINIK ARCTICA.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Ordering like this seems to do what my client expects :)